# How to check and validate duplicate values from onclick event in HTML table through Javascript

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONkAu.jpg

```js
function addinfo()
{
    var c_name = document.getElementById("c_name").value;
    var c_mobile = document.getElementById("c_mobile").value;
    var rows_count = document.getElementById("addinfo").rows.length;
    $('#addinfo').append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="in_sr[]" id="in_sr" value="'+ rows_count +'" readonly/></td><td><input type="text" name="in_cname[]" id="in_cname" value="'+ c_name +'" readonly/></td><td><input type="text" name="in_cmobile[]" id="in_cmobile" value="'+ c_mobile +'" readonly/></td>');
}
```

```css
    table,thead,tr,th,tbody,tr,td{border: 1px solid;}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            table,thead,tr,th,tbody,tr,td{border: 1px solid;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Name : </label><input type="text" name="c_name" id="c_name">
        </br></br>
        <label>Mobile : </label><input type="text" name="c_mobile" id="c_mobile">
        </br></br>
        <button type="button" name="button" onclick="addinfo()">Add Info</button>
        </br></br>
        <table id="addinfo">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sr.</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>    
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could it be in jquery or pure javascript

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.